# How to insert a space char when inputting a node name to `org-roam-node-find`?

Tags: insert, org-roam, insert-char

When I use command `org-roam-node-find` and I want to create a node named `Programming Languages`, I can't enter the space character.

Emacs seems to require the node title to be a single string without spaces. If I try to create a node called "Programming Languages", by entering `C-c n f`, when I hit `SPC` after `Programming`, the minibuffer says `Programming [No match]`.

If I keep going with the whole string Emacs tries to create a node called `ProgrammingLanguages`. I can edit the title in the capture template to add the space, but I can't understand why this is the default behaviour, and I don't know how to change it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always use `C-q SPC` to insert a space char. You can use `C-q` to insert any character. So just type `Programming`, followed by `C-q SPC`, followed by `Languages.

`C-h k C-q` tells us:

> `C-q` runs the command quoted-insert (found in `global-map`), which is an
> interactive compiled Lisp function in ‘simple.el’.
>
> It is bound to `C-q`.
>
> `(quoted-insert ARG)`
>
> Read next input character and insert it.
>
> This is useful for inserting control characters. With argument, insert `ARG` copies of the character.
>
> If the first character you type after this command is an octal digit,
> you should type a sequence of octal digits which specify a character code.
> Any nondigit terminates the sequence.  If the terminator is a `RET`,
> it is discarded; any other terminator is used itself as input.
> The variable `read-quoted-char-radix` specifies the radix for this feature;
> set it to 10 or 16 to use decimal or hex instead of octal.
>
> In overwrite mode, this function inserts the character anyway, and
> does not handle octal digits specially.  This means that if you use
> overwrite as your normal editing mode, you can use this function to
> insert characters when necessary.
>
> In binary overwrite mode, this function does overwrite, and octal
> digits are interpreted as a character code.  This is intended to be
> useful for editing binary files.